# Book after Kreyszig Functional Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

I have finished the book Introductory Functional Analysis by Erwin Kreyszig and enjoyed it a lot. Wonderful book, but I feel that

1. This book did not give knowledge about $L^p$ spaces and Euclidean spaces.
2. I want to read more and modern book on normed spaces
3. I want to study applicable functional analysis

Comment: It is *Erwin Kreyszig*.

Comment: What exactly is your question here?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend

> H. Brezis, Functional Analysis, Sobolev spaces and Partial Differential Equations.